# What is 'request content area'?

Tags: python, python-requests, interfax

I was reading interfax API doc and found these lines of explanation on uploading chunks to an 
existing document upload session.

> The request content area holds the chunk being uploaded.

I'm using `requests` library for this, and I'm wondering what the 'request content area' is.

[link to the API doc](https://docs.uplandsoftware.com/interfax/documentation/api/rest/rest-api-reference/sending-faxes/uploading-documents/upload-chunk/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think it means http post body

Comment: Thank you @Lei Yang!

Comment: Could you post it as an answer so that I can check it.

Comment: i'm not familiar with that api. so i'm afraid i misunderstand. maybe it's better for the official guys to come across your question and answer.

Comment: Okey, I get it.